# How to match loop a single character with multiple characters in a list and return bigger list dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new in flutter and don't know much about dart, and i want ask about my problem.
This my example to graft each character * in listb loop foreach element in lista:

```
void main() {
  var lista = ['1', '2', '3'];
  var listb = ['a***' ,'b*','c'];
  List<String> filter1 = [];
  List<String> filter2 = [];
  List<String> filter3 = [];
 //  
  for (var value in listb) {
      if (value.contains("*"))  {
        for (var aa in lista) {
         filter1.add( value.replaceFirst('*', '$aa'));               
                              }      
                                }
  }
         listb.removeWhere((aaa) => aaa.contains('*'));         
         filter1 = List.from(filter1)..addAll(listb) ; 
  print('filter1' + '$filter1');
//
  for (var value in filter1) {
      if (value.contains("*"))  {
        for (var aa in lista) {
         filter2.add( value.replaceFirst('*', '$aa'));               
                              }      
                                }
  }
         filter1.removeWhere((aaa) => aaa.contains('*'));         
         filter2 = List.from(filter2)..addAll(filter1) ; 
  print('filter2' + '$filter2');
 // 
    for (var value in filter2) {
      if (value.contains("*"))  {
        for (var aa in lista) {
         filter3.add( value.replaceFirst('*', '$aa'));               
                              }      
                                }
  }
         filter2.removeWhere((aaa) => aaa.contains('*'));         
         filter3 = List.from(filter3)..addAll(filter2) ; 
  print('filter3' + '$filter3');


}
```

Result out put

```
filter1[a1**, a2**, a3**, b1, b2, b3, c]
filter2[a11*, a12*, a13*, a21*, a22*, a23*, a31*, a32*, a33*, b1, b2, b3, c]
filter3[a111, a112, a113, a121, a122, a123, a131, a132, a133, a211, a212, a213, a221, a222, a223, a231, a232, a233, a311, a312, a313, a321, a322, a323, a331, a332, a333, b1, b2, b3, c]
```

And it's very bad if character * to be replace in listb is : "a***********" :))
Is there a shotter way to escape one character need replace is a loop to have result filter3 at output? Thks U!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Darish's answer is a cool application of set theory, though I would argue that it is overkill. You can also achieve this with `listB.expand` and a recursive generator method:

```dart
void main() {
  final listA = ['1', '2', '3'];
  final listB = ['a***', 'b*', 'c'];

  final output = listB.expand((term) => permutationGenerator(term, listA)).toList();

  print(output);
}

Iterable<String> permutationGenerator(String input, List<String> replacements) sync* {
  if (input.length == 0) {
    // If the input is empty, there's nothing to generate
    return;
  }
  if (input.length == 1) {
    // If the input is one character, there's no suffix to append
    if (input == '*') {
      // Input is '*' so yield all the values in replacements
      yield* replacements;
    } else {
      // Input isn't '*' so just yield it alone
      yield input;
    }
  }

  // Trim off and cache the first character
  String firstChar = input[0];

  // Recursively process all possible permutations of the input minus
  // the first character
  for (var suffix in permutationGenerator(input.substring(1), replacements)) {
    if (firstChar == '*') {
      // If the first character is '*', replace it with all values in 
      // replacements and append to it the suffix values calculated
      // from the recursive 
      yield* replacements.map((c) => c + suffix);
    } else {
      // The first character isn't '*' so just yield it directly
      yield firstChar + suffix;
    }
  }
}
```

This will output the following list (formatted):

```
[
  a111, 
  a211, 
  a311, 
  a121, 
  a221, 
  a321, 
  a131, 
  a231, 
  a331,
  a112, 
  a212, 
  a312, 
  a122, 
  a222, 
  a322, 
  a132, 
  a232, 
  a332, 
  a113, 
  a213, 
  a313, 
  a123, 
  a223, 
  a323, 
  a133, 
  a233, 
  a333, 
  b1, 
  b2, 
  b3, 
  c,
]
```

Comment: Thks Abidon so much. This way easily to understand with newbie as me ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can create a general solution by taking Cartesian product of the input strings.

---

**Step 1:**

These are the input lists.

```
 var lista = ['1', '2', '3'];
 var listb = ['a***' ,'b*','c'];
```

Split each 'listb' item as shown below

```
listb.forEach((value) {
    ///split the string with asterisk symbol
    var symbols = value.split('*');
}
```

**Step 2:**

For each asterisk symbol, calculate the Cartesian product of the input strings.

```
Iterable<List<String>> product = cartesian(
        List<List<String>>.generate(symbols.length-1, (tempIndex) => lista));
    product.forEach((productValue) {
      ///final output
      print("$symbol${productValue.join()}");
    });
```

The complete snippet is here.

```
 void main() {
  ///strings that we should use for permutation
  var lista = ['1', '2', '3'];
  ///input strings with asterisk that needs to be replaced.
  var listb = ['a***', 'b*', 'c'];
  listb.forEach((value) {
    ///split the string with asterisk symbol
    var symbols = value.split('*');
    for (int i = 0; i < symbols.length; i++) {
      var symbol = symbols[i];
      if (symbol.isNotEmpty) {
        Iterable<List<String>> product = cartesian(
            List<List<String>>.generate(symbols.length-1, (tempIndex) => lista));
        product.forEach((productValue) {
          ///final output
          print("$symbol${productValue.join()}");
        });
      }
    }
  });
}

Iterable<List<T>> cartesian<T>(List<List<T>> inputs) sync* {
  if (inputs.isEmpty) {
    yield List<T>(0);
    return;
  }
  var indices = List<int>.filled(inputs.length, 0);
  int cursor = inputs.length - 1;
  outer:
  do {
    yield [for (int i = 0; i < indices.length; i++) inputs[i][indices[i]]];
    do {
      int next = indices[cursor] += 1;
      if (next < inputs[cursor].length) {
        cursor = inputs.length - 1;
        break;
      }
      indices[cursor] = 0;
      cursor--;
      if (cursor < 0) break outer;
    } while (true);
  } while (true);
}
```

The output is

```
a111
a112
a113
a121
a122
a123
a131
a132
a133
a211
a212
a213
a221
a222
a223
a231
a232
a233
a311
a312
a313
a321
a322
a323
a331
a332
a333
b1
b2
b3
c
```

You can see a live demo [here](https://dartpad.dev/b1832fbd1d7656ef2dc97148b7e4391c) on DartPad.

Comment: Thks u so much Darish. 
I will read slowly to understand your code. A lot of knowledge I don't know yet. But It is certainly useful to write shorter code even though the order of results returns when * in listb is swapped a ** or ** a produces the same result. Once again thank you very much.